# How should I be assigning names to sprites from a sprite sheet?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, sprite-sheet

I know how to load a sprite sheet, clip the images and return a list of those images, but I like to refer to my sprites by name rather than index, to keep the code readable and manageable, but it's sometimes long and tedious writing out lists of sprite names.

I usually create a dictionary, and refer to the sprite I need by name, but I wondered if I should be hard-coding the names?

This is what I usually do:

```py
sprites = load_spritesheet('spr_buttons.png', (64, 64))
BUTTON_NAMES = ['start', 'start_hover', 'start_click', 'back', 'back_hover',
                'back_click', 'skip', 'skip_hover', 'skip_click', 'exit',
                'exit_hover', 'exit_click', 'check', 'check_hover',
                'check_click', 'blank']
spr_buttons = {}
for index, sprite in enumerate(sprites):
    spr_buttons[BUTTON_NAMES[index]] = sprite
```

Using these button sprites as the example, I also have a button class and create a new instance for each button, passing in the name of the sprite.

This works fine, but I want to find a better way. Do I create a .txt file to accompany my sprite sheets and get the names from that? Or do I use a keyword + index number assigned to each sprite (e.g. `button_1`, `button_2` etc.)?

Here is my `NewButton` class:

```
import pygame


class NewButton:
    """Create and maintain a new button."""`

    def __init__(self, name, sprites, x_pos, y_pos, size):
        """Initialise a new button instance.

        :param name:    The name of the button from the dictionary.
        :param sprites: A dictionary of button sprite images.
        :param x_pos:   The x position of the button image.
        :param y_pos:   The y position of the button image.
        :param size:    The squared size of the button image.
        """
        self.img_normal = sprites[name]
        self.img_hover = sprites[name + '_hover']
        self.img_click = sprites[name + '_click']
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x_pos, y_pos, size, size)
        self.image = self.img_normal
        self.hover = False
        self.clicked = False
        self.execute = False
        self.max_timer = 20
        self.click_timer = 0

    def update(self, delta):
        """Update the button instance.

        :param delta: A multiplier based on real time between updates.
        """
        if self.clicked:
            self.click_timer += delta
            if self.click_timer < self.max_timer / 2:
                self.image = self.img_click
            elif self.click_timer >= self.max_timer:
                self.clicked = False
                self.click_timer = 0
                self.image = self.img_normal
                self.execute = True
            else:
                self.image = self.img_normal
        else:
            mx, my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            if self.rect.collidepoint(mx, my):
                self.image = self.img_hover
                self.hover = True
            else:
                self.image = self.img_normal
                self.hover = False

    def click(self):
        """Set the button as being clicked."""
        self.clicked = True

    def reset(self):
        """Reset the execute status of the button."""
        self.execute = False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in a simpler way using the [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function to create the dictionary:

```
sprites = load_spritesheet('spr_buttons.png', (64, 64))

BUTTON_NAMES = ['start', 'start_hover', 'start_click',
                'back', 'back_hover', 'back_click',
                'skip', 'skip_hover', 'skip_click',
                'exit', 'exit_hover', 'exit_click',
                'check', 'check_hover', 'check_click',
                'blank']

spr_buttons = dict(zip(BUTTON_NAMES, sprites))
```

Comment: Thanks @martineau, the `zip()` function has certainly made the process of assigning the images to the names shorter, but as for the whole process of creating a list of names and then assigning them—would you say that is the way to go, or do you know of a more pythonesque way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Jayce: It's hard for me to recommend anything based on what's in your question. You mentioned something about also having a button class and using the name of the sprite but there's no example of that. I also cannot say for sure whether you should hardcode names or not because I don't know what the application is and what makes sense in its context. Applications usually have a fixed number of buttons for their GUI, so I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: It is a game I'm making. I do have a fixed number of buttons in my GUI—those listed in my `BUTTON_NAMES` list. They are the buttons for my title screen, game setup and game screen. I appreciate the help you've given so far, and this is not the first game I've made, but I'm just looking for some advice / affirmation on my methods so far. I'll update the post with my `NewButton()` class if I can.

Comment: Based on the code in your `NewButton` class, I would say the way you're doing it is fine because how you create the `spr_buttons` dictionary is unlikely to affect very much of the rest of your code (just the one-time creation of `NewButton` instances when it starts up). Since the latter are part of your GUI, hardcoding their variable names would probably also be fine. i.e. `start_button = NewButton('start', spr_buttons, x, y, size)`, `back_button = NewButton('back', spr_buttons, x, y, size)`, etc. Having hardcoded names like that for these button objects should facilitate implementing the GUI.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you've to consider, that the [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) in [`pygame.sprite.Group`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group) are not ordered. It is not guaranteed, that the sprites are enumerated in the same order when they group is iterated, as they were append to the group.
See the documentation of [`pygame.sprite.Group`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group):

> The Sprites in the Group are not ordered, so drawing and iterating the Sprites is in no particular order.

---

I recommend to define [`enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html)s which are naming the buttons:

```py
from enum import Enum
class Button(Enum):
    start = 0
    start_hover = 1
    # [...]
```

Create a dictionary where each buttons is associated to an enumerator:

```py
spr_buttons = dict(zip(Button, sprites))
```

So a button can be accessed by e.g.:

```py
sprite = spr_buttons[Button.start]
```

or even by using [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) and a name:

```py
sprite = spr_buttons[getattr(Button, "start")]
```

---

Alternatively you can create a list of buttons and access by the `.value` property of the enumerator, which is the index of the list:

```py
spr_buttons = list(sprites)
sprite = spr_buttons[Button.start_hover.value]
```

Comment: Thanks @Rabbid76, that has certainly given me another way of *using* the buttons, do you also think that creating a list of names and assigning them to the images with `zip()` is the best way to do this? I'm just trying to find the most pythonesque way to do this.

Comment: @Jayce Do the identification need to be a name (string) or can it be any other kind of id? In python the general way to map a kind of identification to an object is a dictionary.  But I recommend to append the association of an object and the id to the dictionary when the object is created.

Comment: Thanks @Rabbid76. Just for the record, I am not using pygame.sprite for this game, I'm using completely custom classes for the sprites. Another thing, dictionary objects are actually kept in the order they are added in - you can test this by creating a dict and then printing it, but regardless, as my sprites are referenced by their name (string), and not by index, that isn't a problem anyway.

Comment: @Jayce I see. If you can make sure, that the list of sprites is in a well defined order, then to `zip` a list of sprites and a list of names is the proper solution. Of course, the solution implies implicit knowledge about the order of images.

Comment: Allow me chime in here. @Jayce: you probably shouldn't be using the term "sprite" for your own variables (or custom types) because `pygame` comes with a built-in [one](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html) that's generally used for purposes other than what it sounds like you're doing (and is what Rabbid76 understandably assumed you were talking about). Secondly, how you intend on _using_ instances of these objects _may_ be an important factor in the design of your game, depending on what's required to reference them and how often that's likely to occur and the amount of code it affects.

Comment: Thank you to you both - I would mark both as the Answer if I could. Yes, I do throw the term "sprite" around a bit too freely, but I'm not actually using it out-of-term, as a sprite *is* a 2D bitmap image, not just a Python class, but in the context of this forum, I probably should use more caution to prevent being misunderstood. Regardless, you have both given me excellent answers, and I thank you both for your help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use sequence unpacking of the sprites to assign them to the names you wish to use:

```
sprites = load_spritesheet('spr_buttons.png', (64, 64))

start, start_hover, start_click, back, back_hover, back_click, \
skip, skip_hover, skip_click, exit, exit_hover, exit_click, \
check, check_hover, check_click, blank = sprites
```

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to hard-code all those sprite names into one's code. A dictionary associating button names to sprites would be better, IMO.

Comment: I agree @martineau, it probably is not a good idea; however, there could be some use cases, it is easy to implement, and that is what the op asked for.

Comment: I think doing it without hard-coding is pretty simple—see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56406022/355230).